# sql : finding how many objects were stolen by a player?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many, logic, one-to-many

### The Database Design :

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f23b3

I have a table `players`

```
CREATE TABLE players (
    id MEDIUMINT(7) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
    name VARCHAR(30)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

A table `objects`

```
CREATE TABLE objects (
    id INT(9) unsigned AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30),
    type VARCHAR(20)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

And a table describing `one-to-many` relation between objects and players (a player can have multiple objects) , but it's not strictly `one-to-many`, as we'll see in a while :

```
CREATE TABLE playerobjects (
    objectid INT(9) unsigned NOT NULL,
    playerid MEDIUMINT(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(objectid,`date`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

the above table might be tricky to understand, but here's what it all means:

- A player can have many objects on any given date
- An object may only belong to one player on any given date
- A player may *steal* an object from another player, which would mean that table `playerobjects` will have two entries for the stolen object with different playerids and different dates
- An object may only be stolen only once per day

Therefore, we can infer from the above guidelines that an object may have many owners but only one per day. Its also possible that player1 may steal some object from player2 and the next day, player2 steals the object back from player one.

### What I Want To Do :

Now, from the above database, I want to find out how many objects a player has stolen and is currently posessing them. Also I want to make a leader-board showing top players ordered by no. of stolen objects.

That said, if Bob had the object first but Emily stole it from Bob and Sheldon stole it from Emily, the query should only show that the object was stolen by Sheldon on some date and nothing else, since Emily did steal the object from Bob but it was a long time ago and the current owner of the object is Sheldon.

### Sample code

```
INSERT INTO  players (name) VALUES ('Bob') , #id 1
        ('Emily') ,  #id  2
        ('Sheldon'); #id 3

INSERT INTO objects (name,type) VALUES ('Choco vanilla','ice cream'), #1 
        ('Butterscotch','ice cream'), #2
        ('Nexus 4','Mobile Phone'), #3
        ('Snoopy','pet'), #4
        ('minecraft','game'); #5

INSERT INTO playerobjects (playerid,objectid,date) VALUES (1,1,'2013-05-15'), 
        (2,2,'2013-05-15'), 
        (3,3,'2013-05-15'), 
        (1,4,'2013-05-15'), 
        (2,1,'2013-05-16'),
        (1,5,'2013-05-16'),
        (3,1,'2013-05-17'), 
        (1,3,'2013-05-18'), 
        (3,3,'2013-05-19'), 
        (3,5,'2013-05-19'),
        (2,5,'2013-05-20');
```

expected result for individual with id 3, rows :

```
        (3,1,'2013-05-17'), 
        (3,3,'2013-05-19')
```

expected result for individual with id 2, row :

```
        (2,5,'2013-05-20')
```

expected result for player 1: none, since the object he stole was re-stolen from him leaving him only with the objects he which werent stolen from anyone.

Expected result for leaderboard query:

```
 sheldon 2
 emily   1
 bob     0
```

### What I've Come Up With :

Leader Board query, gives wrong info, and also is inefficient I think :

```
SELECT tpo.playerid,COUNT(*) as steals
FROM `playerobjects` AS tpo

LEFT JOIN `playerobjects` AS tpo2 ON (tpo.objectid = tpo2.objectid AND tpo.date < tpo2.date)
LEFT JOIN `playerobjects` AS tpo3 ON (tpo.objectid = tpo3.objectid AND tpo.date > tpo3.date)

WHERE tpo2.objectid IS NULL
AND tpo3.objectid IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY (tpo.playerid)
ORDER BY steals DESC
```

query for individual player and detailed info about steal, gives wrong info:

```
SELECT tpo.objectid,tpo.date
FROM `playerobjects` AS tpo

LEFT JOIN `playerobjects` AS tpo2 ON (tpo.objectid = tpo2.objectid AND tpo.date < tpo2.date)
LEFT JOIN `playerobjects` AS tpo3 ON (tpo.objectid = tpo3.objectid AND tpo.date > tpo3.date)

WHERE tpo2.objectid IS NULL
AND tpo3.objectid IS NOT NULL
```

Why these queries give wrong info ? because they also count the previous records of the object. Relating it with the previous Bob Emily Sheldon example, while it should return only the record when Sheldon steals the object from Emily, it also shows the record where Emily had stolen the object from Bob. I don't know how to fix this without using a complicated subquery which'll make the query even more inefficient. I really hope there is some better way to do this.

Comment: Please post some sample data for all your tables and desired output based on it

Comment: Your query and provided schema don't match. What are `vid` and `updated` columns in join conditions?

Comment: mistake, were supposed to be objectid and date. Fixed now

Comment: Here, a fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f23b3

Answer (score 0):

Remove the tpo2 JOIN and replace the tpo2 WHERE clause with

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM `playerobjects` AS tpo2 
    WHERE (tpo.objectid = tpo2.objectid AND tpo.date < tpo2.date)
)
```

That is, instead of JOINing, which causes complications here, just exclude the items that were stolen later.

While you're at it, change your tpo3 "LEFT JOIN" to an "INNER JOIN".

Answer (score 0):

```
select tpo.objectid, tpo.date from playerobjects  as tpo where (select count(*) from playerobjects as tpo2 where ((tpo2.date>tpo.date) and (tpo2.objectid=tpo.objectid)))=0 and playerid=3;
```

Hope this help

Comment: This query fails when retrieving for player 2 and player 1 since it also returns object which player already had, and did not steal. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f23b3/10

Comment: no, please verify 

* for player 2 the true result is (2;5) and not 5 like you have written above 
* for player 1 the true result is 4

In the two cases, the sql code I wrote is then good

Comment: yes it is good for all cases. If you want, give me a case where it does not work.